# WFP stateful filtering in the forwarding layer?

Tags: wdk, wfp

As we know, the Windows Filtering Platform architecture consists of several layers of filtering (combinations of IPv4/6, inbound/outbound, stream/datagram).

One specific layer that as far as I know it's the only one that provides stateful filtering is the ALE layer (Application Layer Enforcement). The intention is to determine an affinity of a packet to a specific TCP or UDP "connection" (packets of the same source/destination ports and IP addresses), instead of inspecting each packet solely as an IP datagram. However, as I understand, the ALE layer is only allowed for connections that has a peer in the local machine, and that has an application in it that handles a party in it.

My question is, is there an easy way to handle stateful connections (particularly for UDP) for filtering **in the forwarding layer** (not inbound or outbound) within the WFP? That is, to filter-by-connections packets that didn't targated for the local machine.

I don't want to fall so low, but I considered receiving of forwarding layer IP packets and redirecting them just for filtering (then redirect again).

Comment: if i remember it right, WFP callout driver is parallel with `tcpip.sys` (`tcpip.sys` call to WFP engine, and WFP engine calls to callout driver). And in Windows, forwarding packets does not go to `tcpip.sys`. So no chance.

Comment: But, there are forwarding callouts for WFP. How this is possible?